# Mass edit photos to add watermark

Tags: photos, watermark

I am looking to add my logo to around 500 pictures as watermark or something similar, Anyone care to recommend a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using windows, [Photoscape](http://www.photoscape.org/ps/main/index.php) is a simply good choice. I used this tool for adding watermark to more than 60.000 pictures in a night! It's got a batch editor for doing any edit on an array of pictures!